# Document versioning service for a file server

Tags: javascript, node.js, svn, version-control, file-storage

Hey there maybe someone can help me out!

I have some (Word) documents on a Windows file server and I want to write an node.js Application which restricts the access to this files. In the App-UI I want to list up all the existing files and maybe open them with Word Online. Also I want to upload new files and keep track of the changes by versioning the documents.

I thought about using Subversion and creating a repository so it would handle the versioning/checking - & out logic but i dont know if thats the right approche. Do you have any kind of experince on using svn like this?

Do you know a tool which would fit my needs any better?

I thought about something like this (See the image). Maybe there is already something which could help me with the versioning process! 
[Here's the link to the Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QBlCB.png)

Thank you folks!

Comment: Welcome to SO, please provide some code you have tried in order to get an accurate response about your problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[VisualSVN Server](https://www.visualsvn.com/server/) should work great for you. You can simply put your documents into Subversion. Download VisualSVN Server from https://www.visualsvn.com/server/download/ **(no registration required)**.

VisualSVN Server supports previewing MS Word (docx) documents in the repository web interface as well as PDF, PSD, AI and Markdown files. See the demo at https://demo-server.visualsvn.com/!/#documents

Here is a demo of previewing a DOCX document: https://demo-server.visualsvn.com/!/#documents/view/head/TypeScript%20Language%20Specification.docx

Comment: Is there a git version?